# Career Recommendation System for Schools

Tags: educational, knowledge-base, artificial-intelligence

I am assisting a charity in the running of a series of career guidance sessions for children typically between the ages of 10-18 years old. Hence we are looking for system that can be used to help guide the children on career choices e.g. degree to pursue at university, vocational training, etc.

It will be based on a series of questions like:

- subjects studying in school e.g. sciences (physics, chemistry, biology, etc), arts (literature, history, etc.), languages (English, French, etc),  design & technology, etc
- Grades & Interests in the subjects etc.
- Maybe some psychometric questions
- and so on...

It should run on Windows or Linux. Preferably self-hosted or standalone, but willing to look at an online system. Preferably free, but open to a reasonable cost (yet to be determined).

I have already searched some of the other forums (datascience, ai, stackoverflow) but most of the questions/answers relate to ideas on how to build, project work, etc.

I know this can get quite complicated, but I am asking whether anyone has come across such a working system or can make any recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question because they're fully commercial paid options, but in case they can help provide you with some more direction (or just more search terms you can Google for :P)... https://www.morrisby.com/morrisby-profile and https://www.fasttomato.com/ are things I've come across in the last few years from school/college

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, thanks for the tips. Had looked at Morrisby a while ago but had not seen Fasttomato. Will revisit and also do more searching...